# easy_install or pip install doesn't find a package

Tags: python, package, debian

I'd like to install python-pythonmagick package 
http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-pythonmagick

but when I run `pip install` or `easy_install` python-pythonmagick, it fails to find the package.

I guess I can add a url to /etc/apt/sources.list
What's the url that I want to add to this file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a Python package that is maintained by the Debian repo. You can install it with the Debian package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pythonmagick
```

or

```
sudo aptitude install python-pythonmagick
```

---

However, I would prefer to stick with `pip` (with `virtualenv`) and use either of the following instead:

```
→ pip search pythonmagick
PythonMagickWand          - Python wrapper for the ImageMagick wand API
PythonMagick              - Wrapper around GraphicsMagick

→ pip search pgmagick
pgmagick                  - Yet Another Python wrapper for GraphicsMagick
```

Note that you will need to install `GraphicsMagick`/`ImageMagick` itself with Debian's package manager separately if you are using `pip`. `pgmagick`/`pythonmagick` is just a Python wrapper for `GraphicsMagick`/`ImageMagick`.

More: [pgmagick](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgmagick/0.3.3)

Comment: wow more than what I asked for! Another question, I installed using apt-get install, and now it works sorta.. It runs outside of virtualenv but not in a virtual-env that I'm working on.  How do I let a virtual-env know about something installed by apt-get?

Comment: I also tried installing apt-get installing ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick. then sudo pip install pythonmagick.. it says "could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pythonmagick'. Strange 'pip search pythonmagic' shows the pythonmagickwand and pythonmagick.

Comment: @Eugene I am afraid `pythonmagick` is no longer active: http://sxoop.wordpress.com/2006/11/29/whither-pythonmagick/ Though if you are using `ImageMagick` you can still `pip` install from the tarballs here: http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/ . Though `pgmagick` seems to be the best option here.

Comment: @Eugene To answer your first question, `apt-get install` will not install the package to the `virtualenv` path. The only way I can think of to make it work with `virtualenv` is to copy the files that gets installed by `apt-get` (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonmagick*` for e.g. ) to your `virtualenv` path (`venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on running vagrant on ubuntu...

```
sudo yum install python-pythonmagick
```