# Convert pdf to jpg using python 2.7- an error

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, jpeg, data-conversion

I try to find a simple python code that convert hundred of pdf files to jpg files to the same folder where the pdf files located. I use this code from [Python Wand converts from PDF to JPG background is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439234/python-wand-converts-from-pdf-to-jpg-background-is-incorrect)

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
import os, os.path, sys

def pdf2jpg(source_file, target_file, dest_width, dest_height):
RESOLUTION    = 300
ret = True
try:
    with Image(filename=source_file, resolution=(RESOLUTION,RESOLUTION)) as img:
        img.background_color = Color('white')
        img_width = img.width
        ratio     = dest_width / img_width
        img.resize(dest_width, int(ratio * img.height))
        img.format = 'jpeg'
        img.save(filename = target_file)
except Exception as e:
    ret = False

return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
source_file = r"C:\Users\yaron.KAYAMOT\Desktop\aaa.pdf"
target_file = r"C:\Users\yaron.KAYAMOT\Desktop\aaa.jpg"

ret = pdf2jpg(source_file, target_file, 1895, 1080)
```

but i get an error:

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows
>>>
```

but i do have module MagickWand in the hard disk as shown in the cmd :
 [image]

UPDATE:
when i try to pip install in the cmd "wand" module i get:
[image]

so,i do have this module. When i try to pip install imagemagick \ ImageMagick i get:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're importing from `wand` module.
You probably haven't installed bindings for Python.

```
pip install Wand
```

See the details here: http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.2/

Also try to do the following:

```
pip search pythonmagick
```

or something like that. Try to install all required packages.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854695/easy-install-or-pip-install-doesnt-find-a-package) may help you.